# How can I simulate an iPhone app running on an iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, appstore-approval

My app keeps getting rejected from the app store based on this rule:

> 2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

I'm trying to figure out how I can test whether my fix is working. How can I simulate "running on an iPad at iPhone resolution" and how can I confirm that it work correctly at both resolutions?

Comment: I've worked on an iPhone only app and it ran fine on the iPad simulator. Maybe you can change your builds so it is iPhone only, and then see what Apple is complaining about just by using the simulator?

Comment: It IS iPhone only...

Comment: And I guess you have run it in the simulator without issue.

Comment: Maybe you have some checks in code that load some views based on device type (iPhone/iPad).

Comment: Also as Paul was saying, you can run iPhone apps on iPad simulator. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `info.plist`, for the key "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" removing any landscape orientations and
leaving only `Portrait (bottom home button)` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to choose an iPad Simulator from the *schemes*-dropdown menu and run it on there even though it is an iPhone-only application. If it runs fine on there, you should be good to go.

Hope that helps :)